# Error trying to load ffmpeg library in dart

Tags: dart, ffmpeg, ffi

I'm a new programmer in de Dart world and I'm trying some stuff to learn more.
I'm trying to create a application that outputs audio from a file. I checked pub and I haven't found anything that suits my needs. So I found about **dart:ffi** and about ffmpeg capabilities.

For the past few days I'm trying to load the ffmpeg libraries (avcodec, avformat, etc.) into my code but I haven't succeded.

This is my code.

```
var libraryPath = path.join(Directory.current.path, 'bin', 'avcodec.dll');
final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(libraryPath);
```

This is the error I got:

```
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'C:\Users\[MYUSER]\Documents\Code\Dart\ffmpeg\bin\avcodec.dll': 126)
```

What I've tried so far:

- Checked the path, it's right;
- Tried to import another library (sqlite3) with success;
- Tried to compile the DLLs myself and also tried prebuilt ones (from the links on ffmpeg site)

My dart version `Dart SDK version: 2.13.4 (stable) on "windows_x64"`

Whats the procedure to properly use the ffmpeg library with dart?

Comment: [The MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) indicates that Windows error code 126 is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` ("The specified module could not be found.").  Can you double-check that the path is correct?  Does `dir "C:\Users\[MYUSER]\Documents\Code\Dart\ffmpeg\bin\avcodec.dll"` show the correct file?

Comment: Also, are the DLLs you're trying to load 64-bit or 32-bit?  A 64-bit process normally cannot load a 32-bit DLL (or vice-versa).  IIRC, that might also result in `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, the path is correct and the dlls are all 64-bit.